# Any reason not to remove Docker as default WSL distro?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the latest version of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) installed, but when I run `wsl` from the command line I get the following error:

```
An error occurred mounting one of your file systems. Please run ‘dmesg’ for more details.
```

I hunted down a few possible explanations and one is the possibility that Docker is set as my default wsl. Sure enough, when I run `wsl -l -v`, the response is:

```
  NAME                | STATE   | VERSION    
* docker-desktop-data | Stopped | 2    
  docker-desktop      | Stopped | 2
```

To correct this, I am told to change the default from Docker to something else with the command `wsl -s distroName` where “distroName” should be changed to … something.

So I have two questions:

1. What should I type instead of “distroName”?
2. Will Docker Desktop still perform as intended if I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using WSL for anything other than Docker Desktop, then it really doesn't matter.

But since you attempted to run `wsl`, it sounds like you may want to try it out.  In that case, you should definitely install a WSL distribution that is meant for interactive use.

The `docker-desktop` and `docker-desktop-data` distributions aren't really intended to be accessed directly by the user, but one of them *will* get set as default if you don't have any other distribution installed.  There's a [proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8727#issuecomment-1218365160) to have a way for Docker to set these as "hidden" so that WSL wouldn't automatically set either as default.

> What should I type instead of “distroName”?

First, install a user distribution.  Which one you choose is up to you, but I typically recommend Ubuntu for first-time installs.  When installing WSL on recent Windows releases, it should be the default.

It's installable via the Microsoft Store -- Just find the one that says "Ubuntu" (with no version number).  It will install the latest release.

Then, in PowerShell;

```
wsl --set-default Ubuntu
```

> Will Docker Desktop still perform as intended if I do this?

Absolutely -- It's really an error/corner-case/oversight that `docker-desktop-data` ever gets set as default anyway, which is why it's nice that the WSL team is considering a method to prevent this.

Comment: Such a clear and helpful response! Thank you!